# How should I model this data?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a need to model the following requirement for a web application (PHP/MySQL5):

A user can compete in a distance-based challenge which consists of entering progress along a defined round-the-world route

- A JS map displays an individual user’s progress in distance based on the
  distance they have covered in the challenge relative to the total
  target distance (a user updates **distance covered** periodically)
- A Challenge can have many **lat/long points** through which the
  challenge route travels
- More than one user can participate in the same challenge

I have roughly sketched how I would do this but would appreciate advice on the DB design. Initially there will actually only be one pre-defined challenge as this is for a prototype but I would like to model the data in such a way that it can cope with future development e.g. Users challenging other users to a 'race;' i.e participating in the same challenge and displaying both their paths on the same map.

Tables:

**challenges**

- id
- title
- total distance

**challenge_coordinates**

- id
- lat
- long
- challenge_id

**challenges_users**

- user_id
- challenge_id
- distance_covered

I already have a user-management system in place with a users table.

Comment: If it's a virtual race, why use waypoints? Just track the distance.

Comment: Have I asked my question incorrectly? I am interested in whether the data model is correct rather than whether I should/shouldn't be using waypoints.

Comment: Ok. In the current model, you only know the distance covered. In SQL, how would you calculate the last waypoint passed given only distance? Same question, but now with  waypoint id-s not consecutive. What if it's a circular path? What if there are alternative paths?

Answer (score 1):

What you've modelled is a snapshot of the user's total progress.

I think you might want to track the user progress a little differently.  Instead of letting them enter their distance covered directly, why not track their way-points?  If you make a kind of audit trail of where they went (lat/lon) and when (date) then you can easily calculate their distance covered using [Vincenty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) or another numerical method.

By tracking the progress on a map (i.e. by lat/lon) by date you can have more interesting reporting of the data.  For example, what if two "contestants" want to race but can't start in the same place at the same time?  How do you compare their progress?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason for this is that it is a virtual race based on distance travelled on a machine at a gym which the user has to enter - this is in the spec and won't be changed.

Comment: Still, don't you think that an audit trail of incremental distances by date would be more interesting than a total distance per user and race?  Even if the user were to enter their total distance at any given time, wouldn't it be potentially useful to have a dated record of that which would allow you to show progress over time?